# How to import in Java Python subclasses that use abstract methods of other classes?

Tags: java, python, abstract-class, jython

We need to use in Java written software some Python subclasses of an abstract Python class. Trying to do it with Jython we had some troubles that we haven't experienced importing not-abstract Python classes. More specifically, the error that we get is this

> the source attachment is not contain the source for the file PyTableCode.class

Does anybody knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Code would really be needed, but my gut feeling is, that your system has access to the compiled .class file from Jython but not the .py source file